# Showing garbage values when adding two matrix using operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, garbage

Please help me as I am new to programming and I have made this program and it looks fine to me but I am getting garbage values instead of sum of two matrix.I have applied the concept of operator overloading to find the sum of two matrices but I am getting garbage values again and again?Please help me that where is the problem?Thanks.Any help is completely appreciated

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class Matrix {
private:
    int matrix[2][2];
public:
    Matrix operator + (Matrix Sum)
    {
        Matrix sum[2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                sum[i][j].matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + Sum.matrix[i][j];
                return(sum[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    void setMatrix(int m[][2])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    void Display() 
    {
          cout << "\n\nThe matrix finally equals: ";   
         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            cout << " ";
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
               cout<<matrix[i][j];
                if (j == 2 - 1)
                    cout << endl;
            }
        } 
    }
};


int main()
{
    Matrix m1, m2,sum;
   
    const int size=2;
    int matrix1[size][size];
    int matrix2[size][size];
    cout << "Enter the values of matrix 1 (2 X 2)\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter the values of matrix 2 (2 X 2)\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout <<"\n\nSetting the values now\n\n";
    m1.setMatrix(matrix1);
    m2.setMatrix(matrix2);
    sum = m1 + m2;
    cout << "\n\nMatrix 1 (2 X 2) is : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            cout << matrix1[i][j] << "  ";
            if (j == size - 1)
                cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nMatrix 2 (2 X 2) is : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            cout << matrix2[i][j] << "  ";
            if (j == size - 1)
                cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nSum of two matrices is equal to (2 X 2) is : ";
    sum.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to spend some time [to explain your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (or room-mate or other suitable alternative). You have at least two problems with your `operator+` function that such an explanation should help you find.

Comment: In `Matrix operator + (Matrix Sum)` you have `return(sum[i][j]);` inside the innermost loop.  So (1) it shouldn't compile and (2) it would return 1st time into the inner loop.

Comment: @RichardCritten thought so to, but `sum[i][j]` is actually a `Matrix`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Can you please tell me the problem with my operator +

Comment: @churill just spotted that `sum `and `Sum` in the same function

Comment: @Richard Critten But the program compiled and as I have shown the output but the problem is that it shows garbage values

Comment: @Richard Critten yes but as c++ is case sensitive so it might not be the problem

Comment: You're returning on your first loop iteration, so neither `i` nor `j` will have any value other that `0`. Only `sum[0][0].matrix[0][0]` will have an initialized value; the other 3 matrix entries will be garbage.

Comment: @bilal it's not a problem for the compiler - it is a problem for us error-prone humans

Comment: As mentioned you return way to early, and return a `Matrix` object whose internal `matrix` array isn't fully initialized (the majority of its contents will be *indeterminate* and lead to *undefined behavior* when you use it). The second problem is that you most likely don't want `sum` to be an array of arrays of `Matrix` objects, but just a plain `Matrix` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a close look at you `operator+`, there are two major errors:

- `Matrix sum[2][2];` is an array of matrices, but you want to return only a single `Matrix`, not multiple. Also the name is bad, because you already have a parameter with a similiar name. And yes, C++ is case sensitive, but such similiar names are problematic for human readers ;).
- Look where the `return` is. It will return *during* the first iteration, e.g.

  ```
  sum[i][j].matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + Sum.matrix[i][j];
  ```

  will be called just once, with `i` and `j` being zero. Thus it sets only *one* entry and returns immediately afterwards (leaving the other 3 values uninitialized). That's where the garbage values come from, technically it's undefined behaviour.

Here is what the function should look like, but please don't just copy-paste, but take some time to understand it.

```
Matrix operator + (Matrix rhs) // One of the two names needed to change.
{
    Matrix sum; //only one value with a proper name
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // better be explicit and use this, imo
            sum.matrix[i][j] = this->matrix[i][j] + rhs.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return sum; // return only after all the calculations.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you've answered well with full explanation.Deeply Appreciated.

Comment: but the compiler is not allowing to return result

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo, must be `return sum;`

Comment: No problem sir thanks I now understood bundle of thanks

Comment: @bilal Not sure if there can be an answer to this. Mostly it's training. Just trying new stuff, making tons of silly mistakes and learning from them.

Comment: Thank you very much I will remember you as one of my teachers